# Xorg, how to make display resolution larger than physical?

Tags: xorg, scrolling, netbook

Trying to fit 1024x768 VMWare viewport into 1024x600's netbooks display.

Neither the options of allowing VMWare to scale the picture or to set a mythical resolution like 1003x533 for guest, nor using VMWare's window scrollbars are appreciated.

Instead, a no-scrollbars window of 1100x768 and a virtual resolution of ~1280x800 is wanted; X scrolling worked fine for me years ago.

`gtf`  generates a physical bounds for display; how to set a software bounds for a screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, a decent version of xrandr (xrandr 1.3) is required , and the tune to xorg.conf may look like:

```
Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen0"
Device     "Card0"
Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Modes "1280x1024"
    Depth   24 
    Virtual 1280 1024
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

So it is needed to extremely upgrade my favorite Slax.
I did a gentoo install onto this machine, but still didn't applied this tweak+xmonad layout hack to display dzen2 somewhere below the bottom line; 1024x900 (?) mode for my netbook would be generated with GTF.

If you need this expanded NOW! - comment.

Comment: Cool! I did it but how to do it as default screen resolution? I'm using Slax...

Comment: @kokbira, I've been playing with Slax alot.. you have two ways. 1) make a module which contains xorg.conf at proper path and put it to base/ directory - this will affect even 'boot to RAM' fresh configuration 2) if you have changes written to disk, just edit the config, Slax should not overwrite it

Comment: @kokbira, I've found even better thing to do, try this: `xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate normal --scale 1.41x1.41` and get a software resolution scaling (not to mention that VMWare had its own software scaler which allowed me to fit a whole QXGA VM to netbook's screen first).

Comment: interesting, @kagali-san! i'll test these days. thanks